# tense and aspect: had imagined or imagined?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, past-vs-past-perfect

In the following passage, could "had ever imagined" be replaced by "ever imagined"? Any difference of meaning?

> More than ever before, our language and our ideas about language are changing as rapidly as the world around us. Our Information Age has been made possible, of course, by the ever-expanding technology of computers and the extraordinary explosion of information from the Internet and World Wide Web. We are receiving more information than we **had** ever **imagined** possible.

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

"Had ever imagined" just adds more depth to the statement by suggesting that you have been imagining, or thinking about something for an extended period of time. It also suggests that you might have imagined multiple possibilities or different scenarios. By contrast, saying "I imagined..." normally would just imply you had a single preconception.

Also, it is common to hear the phrase "than we *could ever have* imagined", which suggests that the reality is beyond the limits of your imagination; that is you were not capable of imagining it.

Comment: I was taught that the past perfect needs a past event as its anchor point. Is there one in that quoted passage?

Comment: @Apollyon: Ordinarily, yes, but you could say that the past perfect *implies* a past event if there is not one mentioned. In this case, the implied past event is something like, "how things were some time ago". Some time ago, we thought about technology and where (we imagined) it could take us. Now, we find that it is beyond what we *had imagined*.